How can I make the webRTC and signaling feature code production ready?
I am learning webRTC and tried to implement signaling service through websockets. I am still a beginner in backend development so not sure how correct my code is. Can you please review it and let me know the mistakes and how can I make scale it for multiple users using the service in real-time?
server code
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

const fs = require("fs");

console.log(path.join(__dirname, "../public"));

// Express Middleware for serving static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client")));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/client1.html'));
});

var users = 0;
var roomCount = 1;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.join("room" + roomCount);
  users++;

  if (users == 1) {
    users++;
    io.to(Array.from(socket.rooms)[1]).emit("becomeClient1");
  } else {
    users = 0;
    roomCount++; // assuming roomCount won't overflow
    socket.emit("becomeClient2");
    io.to(Array.from(socket.rooms)[1]).emit("notifyClient1");
  }

  socket.on("client1offer", (client1offer) => {
    console.log("cl1 offer--------" + JSON.stringify(client1offer));
    socket.broadcast.to(Array.from(socket.rooms)[1]).emit("client1offer", client1offer);
  });

  socket.on("client1IceCandidates", (client1iceCandidate) => {
    console.log("ice--------" + client1iceCandidate);
    socket.broadcast.to(Array.from(socket.rooms)[1]).emit("client1IceCandidates", client1iceCandidate);
  });

  socket.on("client2answer", answer => {
    console.log("cl2 answer emit");
    socket.broadcast.to(Array.from(socket.rooms)[1]).emit("client2answer", answer);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("----socket close----------");
  });
});

server.listen(8082, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:8082');
});


user end code for video calling feature
let localStream;
let remoteStream;

const servers = [{
  urls: [
    "stun.l.google.com:19302",
    "stun1.l.google.com:19302",
    "stun2.l.google.com:19302"
  ]
}];

const lc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
const dc = lc.createDataChannel("channel");
const rc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);

async function init() {
  try {
    localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false });
    document.getElementById("user-1").srcObject = localStream;

    console.log("Local stream obtained successfully.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error accessing local media stream:", error);
  }
}

init().then(() => {
  console.log("--------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
  var socket = io();
  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("WebSocket connected");

    rc.addEventListener("track", e => {
      console.log("Track received:", e.track);
      if (e.streams && e.streams[0]) {
        document.getElementById("user-2").srcObject = e.streams[0];
      }
    });

    lc.addEventListener("track", e => {
      console.log("Track received from remote:", e.track);
      if (e.streams && e.streams[0]) {
        document.getElementById("user-2").srcObject = e.streams[0];
      }
    });

    localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
      lc.addTrack(track, localStream);
      console.log("Tracks added to lc.");
    });

    localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
      rc.addTrack(track, localStream);
      console.log("Tracks added to rc.");
    });
  });

  socket.on("error", (error) => {
    console.error("WebSocket error:", error);
  });

  socket.on("becomeClient1", () => {
    console.log("Received becomeClient1 event");

    socket.on("notifyClient1", () => {
      console.log("Client 2 joined.");

      try {
        dc.onmessage = e => console.log("Received message: " + e.data);
        dc.onopen = e => {
          console.log("Data channel connection opened.");
          dc.send("heyyyyyy");
          socket.disconnect();
        };

        lc.createOffer().then(o => {
          lc.setLocalDescription(o);
          console.log("Local description set successfully." + JSON.stringify(o));
          socket.emit("client1offer", o);
        });

        lc.onicecandidate = event => {
          console.log("New ICE candidate. " + JSON.stringify(event));
          if (event.candidate) {
            socket.emit("client1IceCandidates", event.candidate);
          }
        };
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error setting up client 1:", error);
      }
    });

    socket.on("client2answer", answer => {
      lc.setRemoteDescription(answer).then(() => {
        console.log("remote description for cl1 set");
      });
    });
  });

  socket.on("becomeClient2", () => {
    console.log("Received becomeClient2 event");

    try {
      rc.onicecandidate = e => {
        console.log("New ICE candidate.");
      };

      rc.ondatachannel = e => {
        rc.dc = e.channel;
        rc.dc.onmessage = e => {
          console.log("Received message from client 1: " + e.data);
          rc.dc.send("supp");
        };
        rc.dc.onopen = e => {
          console.log("Data channel connection opened.");
        };
        socket.close();
      };

      socket.on("client1offer", offer => {
        console.log("-------------<<>>>>>>");
        rc.setRemoteDescription(offer).then(() => {
          console.log("cl1 offer set");
          rc.createAnswer().then(answer => {
            rc.setLocalDescription(answer);
            socket.emit("client2answer", answer);
          }).then(() => {
            console.log("Local description for cl2 set.");
          });
        });
      });

      socket.on("client1IceCandidates", client1IceCandidate => {
        console.log("cl1 ice ---> " + client1IceCandidate);
        rc.addIceCandidate(client1IceCandidate);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error setting up client 2:", error);
    }
  });
});



I opened several tabs in my browser and its working properly but not sure how reliable the app will be if deployed.
Please point out the mistakes and things I need to improve/learn.

You say you are a beginner but that's a big step for a beginner :D You are brave.

Cross-posted on Stack Overflow
